# Email hyperlink redirection unexpected behaviour for particular user

Tags: hyperlink, servicenow

I am a techincal support engineer. I got a issue repporting from a customer that an ITIL user is facing an issue while checking his ticket status over email. when ever he is clicking on the hyperlink which any user receives over email, it is redirecting him to the backend page(Platform) of the instance as part of his initial click. Once he tries to make a second click it is then routing him to the actual page. He is the only user who is facing this issue. Is there any particular KB articles or community articles for these kind of issue. Please note this is the issue with one particular user. Please help me

I am expecting to find why only one particular is able to redirect to backend page at his first click. Usually it should not redirect like that. Please help me with resolution for this issue.